# Angular2 DateTime masking

Tags: angular, datetime, masking

I'm using Angular2TestMask in my application for masking.For date field the mask I'm using is this

```
dMask = [/[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '/',/[0-9]/, /[0-9]/,'/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

But now I need to mask date time filed.How can I do that. If it is not with Angular2TextMask then please suggest me any other masking component compatible with Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

```
time = [/[0-1][0-9]/, /[0-5][0-9]/ , /[0-5][0-9]/] + ([AaPp][Mm]))
```

Comment: Thanks Arvind but I need to display time in AM/PM format like 09:36 PM

Comment: Arvind can you please show me how can I combine both date and time mask.I need single mask which should incorporate both date and time.

Comment: create a plunker with date alone I will modify it for date time

Comment: Sorry @Aravind I have tried this but it is taking 19:59:59 which is wrong in 12-hour format. I have tried and searched for around 2 and half days. but didn't get an appropriate solution. Thanks.